# How do i restore old MongoDB files? (extensions end with numbers)

Tags: mongodb

How can I restore an old MongoDB backup that I believe was made by copying the raw db files? (They did not use a dump command)

It was delivered compressed in a `.7z` format, which decompressed to the following files:

```
mydb_2014.1
mydb_2014.2
mydb_2014.3
mydb_2014.4
mydb_2014.5
mydb_2014.ns
```

I've tried `mongorestore` but it generates errors saying "don't know what to do with file ..., skipping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to just start up a mongod instance while specifying the path to the files in question:

```
mongodb --dbpath /path/to/files
```

You should try to use a version of MongoDB that matches to the version that was in use when the backup was taken. It looks like these files are from the MMAPv1 storage engine, so you may also need to specify `--storageEngine mmapv1` if you're using MongoDB 3.2 or later.